# Margin-top not working for certain elements

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 2 elements that are not responding to `margin: 260px 0 0 0;` or `margin-top: 260px;`. And I don't know why. When I open dev tools in IE and inspect the element, the margin is there, but the element stays at teh top of the div as if `margin: 260px 0 0 0;` was not set at all.

Why isn't margin working for the `a` element inside `.SideContainer a {...}` or `.RightSide a {...}`?

```
        <section class="RightSide SideContainer">
            <a href="~/Shared/Services/WebDevelopment">Packages &amp; Pricing</a>
        </section>


    .SideContainer h1 {
        color: white;
    }

    .SideContainer a {
        margin: 260px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background-color: #ec462f;
    color: white;
    }

.RightSide {
    float: right;
}

    .RightSide a {
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-distinctions-between-inline-and-block-html-elements/6094821

Answer (score 3):

Anchor tags are `inline` elements, so the top and bottom margin styles aren't applied to them as expected. Set the `display` property to `inline-block`, it should work.

```
.SideContainer a, .RightSide a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Keep in mind that setting an element's `display` property to `inline-block` will cause spaces in the source code to be rendered. [Here's](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) how you can prevent that.

An alternative would be to set the `display` property to `block` and set the `float` property if required.

```
.SideContainer a, .RightSide a {
    display: block;
    float: left; /*if required*/
}
```

Comment: inline-block seems to me the best answer since it keeps element as an inline-boxe. defaut value , inline, for <a>  does take no vertical margin nor vertical padding. Aside, padding-top on parent would do it. Line-height and vertical-align could be an option too, but i wonder why the op needs such a fix ? To me, not enough HTML to have a real opinion on what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your anchor tags are inline elements and don't respond to margin.

If you add `display:block` to your CSS on .SideContainer a, it will move.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Girwh

Answer (score 0):

Inline element doesn’t respond to margin.

You need to make the a tag display block or you can float it to right so it will behave right like regular "a" tag and will respond to margin too.

try this:

```
.RightSide a {
    margin-top: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your code, you have to put `display:inline-blcok` in the anchor tag to get `margin-top`.

 
**Solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .SideContainer h1 {
                color:white;
            }
            .SideContainer a {
                padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
                background-color:#ec462f;
                color:white;
            }
            .RightSide {
                float:right;
            }
            .RightSide a {
                display:inline-block;
                margin-top:200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="RightSide SideContainer">
            <a href="~/Shared/Services/WebDevelopment">Packages &amp; Pricing</a>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough to add display:block

```
.RightSide {
margin-top: 200px;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float your 'a' tag like so:

```
.SideContainer a {
    ...
    float:left;
}
```